# Continuous scrolling image banner Jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, slider

I have a client who has requested a continuous sliding banner, basically it's one image that moves from left to right over 5 seconds, I know how to do that, I just need to know how to set it up so it loops and it plays like a continuous animation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function slide() {
          $(".img1").stop(true).animate({'left' : '960px'}, 5000);
        }

        slide();
     });
```

Thanks

EDIT

ok trying this, still not looping, have been trying setIntervals but not working, I know I'm missing something simple, but what

```
    function slide(){  
        $('.homepageslider').animate({   'left' : '0px'  }), 
            { duration: 5000,
                complete: function() {  $(".homepageslider").css('left','-2028px');
                     slide();    
            }
            }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#book').animate({
   'left' : '960px'
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    complete: function() {
     //reset image position
      $(".img1").css('left','0px');
     // activate animation again
       slide();

    }
  });
```

I prefer appending clone of image after the current image and removing previous image once its out of sight so it looks seamless but you can try above code also.

Comment: having trouble getting it to loop still - the image resets but can't find a way to start it again, been trying setinterval, but it's messing around as theres 2 functions im guessing

Comment: try declaring the function slide() outside document.ready. Only keep its function call inside document.ready.